# C# creating attribute that indicate running code after property call

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, properties, attributes

I would like to create an Attribute to put on properties.

The properties that will contains this attribute will execute another method after setting a new value.

For example:

```
    [MethodExecute(Log)]
    [MethodExecute(Save)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }
```

Here I would like to activate two methods, one will log the change and the other will save it.

Thanks,
   Ronny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you could do this in [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). You'll need to specify the method name as a string unfortunately - there's no operator in C# to resolve a method name into `MethodInfo`, although it's been proposed a few times.

You may need to move the attribute if you need the code to execute *only* after the setter (rather than the getter):

```
public string Name
{ 
    get; 
    [MethodExecute("Log")] [MethodExecute("Save")] set;
}
```

(This uses an automatically implemented property for simplicity.)

Answer (score 3):

What you are really asking about is whether the .NET framework has any hooks for Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP). Unfortunately, the answer is *no*, not by default.

There are many frameworks that allow you to do this, but most require that the types so decorated are being created by a specialized factory.

- Many DI Containers have so-colled Interception capabilities that allow you to do that. An example of such a DI Container is [Castle Windsor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309507.aspx).
- Microsoft patterns & practices once made the [Policy Injection Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309507.aspx) that enables such a scenario.
- In more specialized cases you also see this in certain sub-frameworks - e.g. ASP.NET MVC has something called ActionFilter that work that way, but only when hosted by the MVC pipeline.

There are also a few frameworks that allow you do this by modifying the IL after it was compiled, but as I understand it there are some pretty serious disadvantages as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [interception mechanism provided by Unity](http://www.ctrl-shift-b.com/2009/03/implementing-inotifyproperychanged-with.html) dependency injection container. Consider [Implementing INotifyProperyChanged with Unity Interception](http://www.ctrl-shift-b.com/2009/03/implementing-inotifyproperychanged-with.html) as an example.